# I have a .sql file and import it but I attempt throws an error which says it esiste the table but I'm just creating the database and table in this way

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a .sql file and import it but I attempt throws an error which says that the table already exists but I'm just creating the database and table in this way

```
CREATE DATABASE `bancoproyectos2010` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `bancoproyectos2010`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accion` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_asun` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_es` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_prog` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_PE` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_acc` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_Accion` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_asun` (`id_asun`),
  KEY `id_es` (`id_es`),
  KEY `id_prog` (`id_prog`),
  KEY `id_PE` (`id_PE`),
  KEY `num_acc` (`num_acc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=177 ;
```

throws me:
MySQL said:

> 1050 - Table '`bancoproyectos2010`.`acción`' already exists

the database is created from scratch and when it reaches the table creates the .ibd file but does not appear in phpmyadmin but when trying to create a table from phpmyadmin also throws the error that already exists

> 1050 - Table '`bancoproyectos2010`.`acción`' already exists

Comment: the problem is that the table is not created or does not appear anywhere and not by saying that already exists. From phpmyadmin I open the database and is empty and try to create a table named Accion and appears as that already exists. DROP TABLE what had already tried and it makes no difference, because the REPAIR TABLE does not fail but still have the same problem. inside the database reaches create 2 files that are: accion.ibd db.opt

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accion`
REPAIR TABLE `accion`
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you think that this is a solution?

Comment: the problem is that the table is not created or does not appear anywhere and not by saying that already exists. From phpmyadmin I open the database and is empty and try to create a table named Accion and appears as that already exists. DROP TABLE what had already tried and it makes no difference, because the REPAIR TABLE does not fail but still have the same problem

Comment: inside the database reaches create 2 files that are:

accion.ibd
db.opt

Comment: By default, all InnoDB tables and indexes are stored in the system tablespace. As an alternative, you can store each InnoDB table and associated indexes in its own data file. This feature is called “file-per-table tablespaces” because each table has its own tablespace, and each tablespace has its own .ibd data file. I am not sure but if you try to delete the accion.idb file maybe it will work. Before doing this keep a file backup.